# Logging parent thread name in executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, logging, spring-integration

I'm using Spring `task:executor` in a spring-integration context. When the task gets called, the log look like below:
`2015-04-21 10:56:14,371 INFO  [com.Class] (activatorExecutor-2:null) Processing user: abc`
Below is my log4j conversion pattern:
`%d %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n %throwable{10}`
Question is, is it possible to put the calling thread's name into the MDC, or as a prefix to the child thread's name, like this:
`2015-04-21 10:56:14,371 INFO  [com.Class] (activatorExecutor-2:parentThread1) Processing user: abc`
or this:
`2015-04-21 10:56:14,371 INFO  [com.Class] (parentThread1_activatorExecutor-2:null) Processing user: abc`
so that I can correlated back to which thread activated this executor task.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a full-blown-well-thought-out solution for this, but I recommend taking a look at the [Java Configuration approach](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html).

I can see that you should be able to choose an implementation of `Executor` to use for running your threads via [`@EnableAsync`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) and [`AsyncConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer.html).  The implementation provided in the example ([`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html)) has a method [`ExecutorConfigurationSupport#setThreadFactory(ThreadFactory)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setThreadFactory-java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory-) which you could use to customize how the threads are created.

You could create an implementation of `ThreadFactory` that utilizes a delegate `ThreadFactory` for actually creating the threads, but you would now have a hook that would allow you to name the threads according to your criteria.  Wire this up as mentioned above, and hopefully it works out for you.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAsync
 public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

      @Bean
      public MyAsyncBean asyncBean() {
          return new MyAsyncBean();
      }

      @Override
      public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
          ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
          executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
          executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
          executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
          //executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
          executor.setThreadFactory(myThreadFactory());
          executor.initialize();
          return executor;
      }

      public ThreadFactory myThreadFactory() {
          return new MyCustomThreadFactoryThatKnowsHowToProperlyNameThreads();
      }

      @Override
      public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
          return MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
      }
  }
```

This is where the not-so-well-thought-out part comes into play.  I figured I would let you come up with the `ThreadFactory` implementation that best suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Understood that it'll work by adding a customized `ThreadFactory` to append the parent thread name before calling the child thread, and set it back after thread complete. Just wondering is there any easier way to config this in `Spring`, seems like a pretty common requirement to log where the thread coming from.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a simpler Spring based approach. This is what I would use, but I use Java Configuration for everything when I do Spring development, so it isn't too much overhead at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Your log4j pattern is ok (nested diagnostic context), but you need to feed it yourself, by calling:

```
org.apache.log4j.NDC.push("parentThread1");
```

... in the "appropriate place".

---

Alternatively you use "mapped" diagnostic context, with pattern:

```
... %X{myKey} ...
```

..and feeding:

```
org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("myKey", "parentThread1");
```